# _this.parse is not a function --> a scoping issue?

Tags: typescript

I have an angular 4 component which has the following methods.

```
private parseResponse (response: Response) : Dimension[] {
    let responseBody : any[] = response.json();
    console.log(responseBody); // I see an array of objects here
    return responseBody.map( (x) => this.parseDimension(x)); // (********) 
}

private parseDimension (dimension) : Dimension {
    console.log("called"); // <- I never see this in the console
    let retVal = new Dimension(
        dimension["DimensionCode"],
        dimension["DimensionLabel"],
        dimension["DimensionDescription"]
    )
    return retVal }
```

I read that the fat arrow lambda expression should preserve the context.
I get this instead

> TypeError: _this.parseDimension is not a function
>       at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:222:61
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at

where the line refers to (********)

I also tried a simple lambda like the one before (in the same component) which works

```
getDimensions() : Observable<Dimension[]> { 
    return this.http.get(this.endpoint)
        .map(this.parseResponse)
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the entire class and how the method `parseResponse` is invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `this.parseResponse` is not bound to the current context when you did `return this.http.get(this.endpoint) .map(this.parseResponse)`.

You can just wrap it inside an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) before you pass it as a callback to `map`:

```
getDimensions(): Observable {
    return this.http.get(this.endpoint).map((params) => this.parseResponse(params));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, change from method into property (function property) would help

```
// instead of 
private parseDimension (dimension) : Dimension {
  ...
}
// this way the scope will be kept as expected
private parseDimension = (dimension) : Dimension => {
  ...
}
```

Also, check [here the difference in generated code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Dimension%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20parseDimensionx(dimension)%3A%20Dimension%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20way%20the%20scope%20will%20be%20kept%20as%20expected%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20parseDimension%20%3D%20(dimension)%3A%20Dimension%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)